# Creating object and reading from file

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have an object and I can create it with two constructors

```
public Brick(int x, int y){
    ..........
}
```

and

```
public Brick(int x, int y, float sizeX, float sizeY){

}
```

In my map.txt I have this

```
Brick 320 0
Brick 640 64 64 128
Spike 5 12
Spike 75 25
...
...
...
```

and here how I read that file

```
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("data/map.txt");
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(file.readString());
        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            String type = tokens.nextToken();
            if(type.equals("Block")){
                list.add(new Brick(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Float.parseFloat(tokens.nextToken()), Float.parseFloat(tokens.nextToken())));
            }
```

so I need to read my file that both of my constructors would work?

Comment: Sorry, that's just a statement with a question mark tacked on the end. I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is. What's the actual problem that you're trying to ask about?

Comment: As you can see now when I read from a txt file I invoke second constructor (with 4 arguments) but sometimes I need to create Brick with only 2 arguments. So is it possible to read correctly from txt file? Basically I need to read line while there are numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each line has a command then I would read it line by line like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class readFile {

    public static class Brick{
        public Brick(int a,int b){System.out.println("constructor for 2 params: "+a+", "+b);}
        public Brick(int a,int b,int c,int d){System.out.println("constructor for 4 params: "+a+", "+b+", "+c+", "+d);}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String line;

        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("map.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line.trim());
            while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
                String type = tokens.nextToken();
                if(type.equals("Brick")){
                    int params = tokens.countTokens();
                    switch(params){
                        case 2: new Brick(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()),
                                          Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()));
                            break;
                        case 4: new Brick(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()),
                                          Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()),
                                          Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()),
                                          Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()));
                            break;
                        default: throw new Exception("Wrong line:"+line);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but  maybe it is possible to count arguments in a LINE? I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: tokens.countTokens(); counts arguments in line (note that it has to be called before first nextToken(), otherwise each nextToken() call subtracts 1 )